# What is meant by $C_\mathbb{R}(X)$ is an algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

In a video on Intro. to Functional Analysis course, it was stated that the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ is an algebra, because it has point-wise multiplication defined in addition to the vector-space properties. Somehow this definition is not very satisfying. I searched all over for exactly what is the definition of an algebra in this context and I'm still uncertain. Is someone able to formally sate the definition the lecturer was referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

Comment: In short, an algebra over a field $F$ is a vector space $A$ together with a binary operation called multiplication which turns $A$ into a ring, and such that $\lambda(ab)=(\lambda a)b=a(\lambda b)$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $\lambda\in F$. This is the most common definition. So in an algebra you have $3$ operations: addition, multiplication and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algebra denotes a specific mathematical structure, whose precise definition depends on the context. Usually, the structure has an addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication.

Let $K$ be a field, and let $A$ be a vector space over $K$ equipped with an additional binary operation from $A \times A$ to $A$, i.e if $x$ and $y$ are any two elements of $A$, then $x \cdot y$ is an element of $A$ that is called the product of $x$ and $y$. Then $A$ is an algebra over $K$ if the following identities hold for all elements $x, y, z$ in $A$, and all elements $a$ and $b$ in $K$ :

A1) Right distributivity: $(x+y) \cdot z=x \cdot z+y \cdot z$

A2) Left distributivity: $z \cdot(x+y)=z \cdot x+z \cdot y$

A3) Compatibility with scalars: $(a x) \cdot(b y)=(a b)(x \cdot y)$.

These three axioms are another way of saying that the binary operation is bilinear.

Note: Vector space

A vector space over a field $F$ is a set $V$ together with two binary operations that satisfy the eight axioms listed below. In the following, $V \times V$ denotes the set of the ordered pairs of elements of $V$, and $\rightarrow$ denotes a mapping from one set to another. In this context, the elements of $V$ are commonly called vectors, and the elements of $F$ are called scalars.

- The first operation, called vector addition or simply addition $+: V \times V \rightarrow V$, assigns to any two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ in $V$ a third vector in $V$ which is commonly written as $\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}$, and called the sum of these two vectors.
- The second operation, called scalar multiplication $F \times V \rightarrow V$, assigns to any scalar $a$ in $F$ and any vector $\mathbf{v}$ in $V$ another vector in $V$, which is denoted $a \mathbf{v}$.

Update:-

Furthermore, $C_\mathbb{R}(X)$ denotes the Banach spaces of real valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$.